# Import by fileName is not supportted

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have a django project and a dump.json file in which all the database dump is present.

I am trying to run this command to load data into my django project

```
django-admin loaddata dumpdata.json --settings=~/Workspace/odx-lm/lm/settings/local.py
```

On running the above command from the folder `~/Workspace/odx-lm/`, 
I am getting the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/delhivery/Workspace/odx-lm/odx-lm-env/bin/django-admin.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       management.execute_from_command_line()   File "/home/delhivery/Workspace/odx-lm/odx-lm-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 367, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "/home/delhivery/Workspace/odx-lm/odx-lm-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 316, in execute
>       settings.INSTALLED_APPS   File "/home/delhivery/Workspace/odx-lm/odx-lm-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 53, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)   File "/home/delhivery/Workspace/odx-lm/odx-lm-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 41, in _setup
>       self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)   File "/home/delhivery/Workspace/odx-lm/odx-lm-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py",
>   line 97, in **init**
>       mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name) ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The path should be the path to your `dumpdata.json` file. For example `django-admin loaddata workspace/dumpdata.json`

Comment: I tried this thing too:   django-admin.py loaddata ~/Workspace/odx-lm/dumpdata.json --settings=~/Workspace/odx-lm/lm/settings/local.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value for `settings` must be a Python module path, not a file path.

```
... --settings=lm.settings.local
```

Comment: I tried django-admin.py loaddata dumpdata.json --settings=settings  , but this is giving me error: No module named settings

Comment: Should be `lm.settings`. But really you shouldn't be using `django-admin.py`, you should use `manage.py`, which supplies the settings value automatically.

Comment: In my case, `pytest.ini` had: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = 'path/settings.py'`

Noob move on my part, but this post helped resolve it. Thanks.